# Django: How to limit number of objects returned from a model

Tags: python, django

I have a list of "news" headlines in a database with the following fields: ID, Title, Date. I want to get the ten latest ones (or retrieve all of them if there are less than ten).

Something like:

```
news = News.objects.order_by("date").first(10)
```

Comment: Check out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

Comment: @JonClements Thanks. Do you know if it works with `get_or_404()`?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so - "up to 10" includes no results, so you'd have to check if that was the case, and do the 404 manually

Comment: get_or_404() returns a single object if it exists, while [:10] will return an empty list if there are no objects.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is what you need to do:

```
news = News.objects.order_by("-date")[:10]
```

There are a couple of interesting things going on here.

First, to get the lastest news, you need Descending order. (Thats the "-date" part) [0]

The second part is LIMITing the resultset[1]. This shares the same interface as Python lists  Slicing[2], but those are different things. Please read them carefully.

[0] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets

[2] http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html

Comment: No. objects.get/get_or_404 is to get just 1 instance.

Answer (score 1):

My solution

Object returned is actually a list. With using python list indexing we can get any number of objects. Example added below.

```
'productobj = product_master.objects.all()[0:20]`
```