# How to delete first N items from queryset in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I'm looking to delete only the first N results returned from a query in django. Following the django examples [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) which I found while reading [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13422738/6150284), I was able to limit the resulting set using the following code

```py
m = Model.objects.all()[:N]
```

but attempting to delete it generates the following error

```py
m.delete()
AssertionError: Cannot use 'limit' or 'offset' with delete.
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in django?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can not delete through a limit. Most databases do not support this.

You can however accomplish this in two steps, like:

```
Model.objects.filter(id__in=list(Models.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True)[:N])).delete()
```

We thus first retrieve the primary keys of the first `N` elements, and then use this in a `.filter(..)` part to delete those items in bulk.

Comment: it doesnot work with order_by

Comment: @ratnesh: why do you need an `.order_by(..)` here?

Answer (score 7):

You don't have the option directly. So you should delete it by some advanced ways. For example:

```
not_ideal = Model.objects.all()[N:].values_list("id", flat=True)
Model.objects.exclude(pk__in=list(not_ideal)).delete()
```

Using this way you are finding your not ideal objects and delete everything except them.
You can use anything beside `id`. But id is unique and will help you to optimize.

Notice that in the first line I'm getting the items which are from `N` to the `last`.(Not from the `first` to `N`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
Loop through all filtered objects

```
delatable_objects = Model.objects.all()[:N]
for m in delatable_objects:
    m.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the queryset and apply delete method to the objects.

```
for obj in m:
    obj.delete()
```